# Kafka Streams TopologyTestDriver input-output topic

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I have Kafka Streams unit test based on a really great, reliable and convenient TopologyTestDriver:

```
    try (TopologyTestDriver testDriver = new TopologyTestDriver(builder.build(),
            streamsConfig(Serdes.String().getClass(), SpecificAvroSerde.class))) {

        TestInputTopic<String, Event> inputTopic = testDriver.createInputTopic(inputTopicName,
                Serdes.String().serializer(), eventSerde.serializer());

        TestOutputTopic<String, Frame> outputWindowTopic = testDriver.createOutputTopic(
                outputTopicName, Serdes.String().deserializer(), frameSerde.deserializer());

        ...

     }
```

I'd like to test a bit more complex setup where an "output" topic is an "input" topic for another topology.

I can define several input and output topics inside of the same topology. But as soon as I am using the same topic as an input and output topic within the same topology, I'm getting the following exception:

```
org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.TopologyException: Invalid topology: Topic events has already been registered by another source.
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.InternalTopologyBuilder.validateTopicNotAlreadyRegistered(InternalTopologyBuilder.java:578)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.InternalTopologyBuilder.addSource(InternalTopologyBuilder.java:378)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.graph.StreamSourceNode.writeToTopology(StreamSourceNode.java:94)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.InternalStreamsBuilder.buildAndOptimizeTopology(InternalStreamsBuilder.java:303)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.StreamsBuilder.build(StreamsBuilder.java:558)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.StreamsBuilder.build(StreamsBuilder.java:547)
```

It looks like the TopologyTestDriver doesn't provide possibility to define input-output topics, is that right?

**Update**
To better illustrate what I'm trying to achieve:

```
builder.stream("input-topic, ...)..to("intermediate-topic",...);
builder.stream("intermediate-topic", ...)..to("output-topic",...);
```

and I want to be able to verify (assert) the contents of the "intermeidate-topic" in my unit test. Btw. I cannot "reuse" the result of the call ".to()" in building the next topology part, since that method returns void.

But I only have `testDriver.createInputTopic()` and `testDriver.createOutputTopic()` and no way of defining something like `testDriver.createInputOutputTopic()`.

Answer (score 0):

Using the same topic as input and an output topic should work. However, you cannot use the same topic as input topic multiple times (the strack trace indicates that you try to do this).

If you want to use the same input topic twice, you would just add it once, and "fan it out":

```java
KStream stream = builder.stream(...);
stream.map(...); // first usage
stream.filter(...); // second usage
```

Using the same `KStream` object twice, is basically a "fan out" (or "broadcast") that will send the input data to both operators.

Comment: Mm.. I don't think this is what's happening in my case. I'm aware about the "fan out" trick but trying to achieve something different. To better illustrate:

builder.stream("input-topic, ...)..to("intermediate-topic",...);
builder.stream("intermediate-topic, ...)..to("output-topic",...);

and I want to be able to verify (assert) the contents of the intermeidate-topic in my unit test.

But I only have testDriver.createInputTopic() testDriver.createOutputTopic() and no way of defining testDriver.createInputOutputTopic()

Comment: I guess switching to a full blown embedded Kafka in unit tests is the way I should pick.

Comment: Thanks for the details. Not sure what `testDriver.createInputOutputTopic()` would do? If you call `through()` (or a manual `to()` and `builder.stream()`) the topic will be available and you can just create an `TestOutputTopic` for this topic to verify which data flow through it. If you want to ingest data "from output" in addition, you can also create a `TestInputTopic` for it. -- Does this help?

Comment: Note that `createInputTopic()` and `createOutputTopic()` don't really create topics for the topology -- both create a "handle" (ie, the `Test[In|Out]putTopic` that allows you to pipe data into the topic or consume data).

Comment: Thank you @Matthias I think that the `through()` method (which I was overlooking) is the closest to what I need. I was going to test two independent KStream topologies connected via a topic in a single TopologyTestDriver based unit test. But that's not what I asked, and the `through()` is the perfect answer.